# Iniciar aplicação Ruby no boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Olá, tenho o OpenProject, uma aplicação Ruby on Rails, quero que ela inicie junto ao boot do sistema, coloquei o script para iniciar pelo Upstart, mas ao iniciar o sistema, vejo este erro no meu log:

> /usr/bin/env: ruby: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

O script está assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/openproject/openproject
bundle exec rails server -d >> ~/log
```

Alguém sabe o que fazer?

Comment: O ruby é o do sistema ou vc usa rvm ou algo semelhante?

Comment: Olá Alex, eu uso o rvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando RVM, é necessário criar um wrapper.

Veja como na documentação: https://rvm.io/deployment/init-d

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Alex, eu usei o comando:
rvm alias create openproject ruby-2.1.5p273@openproject

e me retornou isso:
ruby-2.1.5p273 is not installed.
Creating alias openproject for ruby-2.1.5p273....

Bom, usando o ruby -v, a versão instalada é a especificada acima, e não entendi este erro...